# IP reservation valid beyond DHCP

Tags: router, dhcp, dd-wrt, openwrt

In my home network, can I reserve a certain IP to a specific device, preventing that it can be assigned to other devices?

Usually routers allow IP reservation on DHCP, but if someone changes the TCP/IP properties for his PC from DHCP to static, he can assign it the IP I do not want anybody to use.

Is there any way to obtain such a feature? Maybe using dd-wrt or open-wrt?

Comment: You can't prevent someone from changing their TCP/IP settings from the router. Perhaps via Group Policy in Windows or something like that, but your router has no control over that.

Comment: @heavyd, you are right - write an answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible to override a static IP configuration. Enabling DHCP Snooping at the router level (I believe dd-wrt supports this) can help prevent the client from taking down the network or conflicting with an existing host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, but with some restrictions.
IP-address rely on the lower level MAC-address and you can "freeze" MAC-IP table on the router. If someone illegally assign IP-address router will ignore that assignment. Therefore "IP-thief" don't get access to the internet via your router. Until he become smart enough to change his MAC-address too. In that case there is no way to tell legal IP-owner from illegal.

Comment: How could I freeze the mac-ip table on the router to prevent ip theft? I know that it is possible to fake mac address too, but I'm not interested to cover such an event. Thanks.

Comment: `arp -f /path/to/the/file.arp` performed at boot time is enough. `file.arp` contains pairs in form: `12:34:56:78:90:ab  10.11.12.13` one per line. Absence of flag `temp` make that pairs persistent and immute to the theft.

Comment: Where should such a command be run? On the router? On the pc?

Comment: On the router, sure. Router should khow who is who.